# How can i find the highest and the lowest value between rows depending on a condition being met in another column in a pd.DataFrame?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following DataFrame, that is generated every time that I run the script, the DataFrame looks like this:

```
df=


index            time    value  status
0  2020-11-20 20:10:00   10        X
1  2020-11-20 20:20:00   11        X
2  2020-11-20 20:45:00   9         X 
3  2020-11-20 20:45:00   5         Y
4  2020-11-20 21:00:00   4         X
5  2020-11-20 21:05:00   2         Y
6  2020-11-20 21:15:00   4         Y
7  2020-11-20 21:20:00   9         X
8  2020-11-20 21:25:00   5         X

The desired output would be :

    index            time    value  status
    0  2020-11-20 20:20:00   11        X
    1  2020-11-20 20:45:00   5         Y
    2  2020-11-20 21:00:00   4         X
    3  2020-11-20 21:05:00   2         Y
    4  2020-11-20 21:20:00   9         X
```

So my goal here would be to create a new pd.DataFrame with the lowest values of Y and the highest values of X.

Thanks to everyone in advance for all the assistance and support.

Comment: The lowest/highest values of X, Y *given what?*  The lowest value of Y is 2, highest value of X is 11

Comment: The lowest value of Y while the status is == to Y, once the code finds X on the status column its starts to look for the highest value.
Creating then a new DataFrame with each value found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a `groupby` on consecutive values of your DataFrame where the status is the same, sort each grouped DataFrame by `value`, and keep either the first or last value of the sorted DataFrame depending on whether the grouped DataFrame has `status` equal to `X` or `Y`.

Note: I noticed the `time` column of your DataFrame has no impact on the answer, so I didn't include it when I recreated your DataFrame.

```
import pandas as pd

## the time column doesn't matter in your problem
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'value':[10,11,9,5,4,2,4,9,5],
    'status':['X']*3+['Y']+['X']+['Y']*2+['X']*2
})

df_new = pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns)

## perform a groupby on consecutive values
for _, g in df.groupby([(df.status != df.status.shift()).cumsum()]):
    g = g.sort_values(by='value')
    ## keep the highest value for X
    if g.status.values[0] == 'X':
        g = g.drop_duplicates(subset=['status'], keep='last')

    ## keep the lowest value for Y
    elif g.status.values[0] == 'Y':
        g = g.drop_duplicates(subset=['status'], keep='first')

    else:
        pass
    df_new = pd.concat([df_new, g])
df_new = df_new.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
>>> df_new
  value status
0    11      X
1     5      Y
2     4      X
3     2      Y
4     9      X
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, you saved me ahahah tks a lot

Comment: No problem, glad to have helped!